# Container doesn't fit width of all the screen size - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a container with `bootstrap` that always fits the screen size (both height and width). But as you can see in the example, it fits the height well, but when doesn't fit the width of all the screen size.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

This is the code is:

```css
html,body{height:100%;}

.fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container fill">
  <div class="container">This is the title</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">Item 1</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">Item 3</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">Author: Mr. X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap applies a `max-width` attribute to `.container`.

Add this CSS and you should be good:

```
.container {
    max-width: unset;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the suggestion.